# How can I filter Craft Commerce products by the current price

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, filtering

**Building on from this question [How can I filter Craft Commerce products by price](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20093/how-can-i-filter-craft-commerce-products-by-price)**

I have a price filter in the store

Using this code works fine for the normal price

```
{% set queryParams = {
        relatedTo: category,
        defaultPrice: [
            'and',
            '>= ' ~ 0,
            '<= ' ~ 90,
        ]
    }
%}
```

but defaultPrice does not consider sale prices.

So if a product is normally $99 but it is reduced to $89, it won't be returned

I would have expected defaultPrice to store the *current price being charged*. So the sale price if it was on sale.

**Is it possible to filter by price and include sale prices?**

I've spent hours now on something I thought would be simple. It seems the only way to get this information is to get the products and loop through them. Checking for sale prices.

Do I have to create a plugin to make a usable price filter?

Answer (score 1):

https://craftcommerce.com/docs/variant-model#saleprice

The comment on the documentation leads me to believe you can just use `salePrice` for your filtering as it will be equal to the `defaultPrice` if there is no sale.

So:

```
{% set queryParams = {
        relatedTo: category,
        salePrice: [
            'and',
            '>= ' ~ 0,
            '<= ' ~ 90,
        ]
    }
%}
```

Comment: I tried this initially too, but that is part of the variant model so not accessible using `craft.commerce.products`

Comment: `defaultVariant` is, but does not seem to be accessible either.

`{% set queryParams = {
            relatedTo: category,
            defaultVariant: {
                salePrice: [
                    'and',
                    '>= ' ~ 0,
                    '<= ' ~ 90,
                ]
            }
        }
    %}`

Does not work either